# First Custom Post Custom Fields Empty After New Custom Post

Tags: posts, custom-field, customization

I am working on a theme which contains a custom post type with custom fields.

Everything is working perfectly except the when a new custom post is added, the custom fields for the first custom post and first one only are wiped.

```
function save_details(){  
    global $post;  
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "testimonyname", $_POST["testimonyname"]);
}  
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');
```

This is what i am using to save the custom field data

Comment: Where exactly are you calling the `save_details` function? Or is it hooked into something? Do you mean you're using custom fields? Or did you create a custom meta box for your post type?

Comment: sorry, i added a meta box for the post type. I have updated the code with the function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was worse than I thought.

Here is the solution:
[Add New Post (Custom Post Type) Deletes 1 Post's Custom Meta Data](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30634/add-new-post-custom-post-type-deletes-1-posts-custom-meta-data/31105#31105)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `save_post` has an argument `$post_id`, so there's no need to global `$post`. In some cases, `$post` might not actually be set (anymore) when you do this, which is probably why it breaks. Second, you should probably check whether you're storing a revision or not (see below). So your code should look like this:

```
function save_details( $post_id ){  
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        $post_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, "testimonyname", $_POST["testimonyname"] );
}  
add_action('save_post', 'save_details', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Can i ask what the 10,1 is for in the save_post action?

Comment: The 10 is the priority, the 1 is the number of variables that is passed on, in this case 1 :)

Comment: Sorry, but after more extensive testing it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by Joost didn't work for me. Instead I found changing the action from `save_post` to `post_updated` solved my problem.