# Add New Post (Custom Post Type) Deletes 1 Post's Custom Meta Data

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

```
function save_details( $post_id ){  
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    $post_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

update_post_meta( $post_id, "testimonyname", $_POST["testimonyname"] );
}  
add_action('save_post', 'save_details', 10, 1);
```

I have a custom post type with a custom field, but after adding several i noticed that the data in the custom field was missing from some previous entries.

I filled them in again and it looked fine.

Then i clicked the Add New button just once and 1 of my posts has it's custom meta data deleted.

However, it doesn't happen every time i click Add New.

I have tried this solution but to no avail

```
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
```

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks,
Ashley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST["testimonyname"]))
```

Placing this code before the update_post_meta lines worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this will work -- at least not in all cases. This tests to see if the `$_POST['some_custom_variable']` is empty, and if it is empty, it doesn't update. This is fine if the custom field will always contain a value, however you won't be able to empty the custom field's value using this code.

I was stuck with a similar problem and found changing the action call from:

`add_action('save_post', 'save_details', 10, 1);`

to

`add_action('post_updated', 'save_details', 10, 1);`

worked in my case.